# How to add TypeScript 3.7 Optional Chaining support to create react app project

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want the latest features of TypeScript 3.7 in my create-react-app project. Such as optional chaining and nullish coalescing.

I tried creating an entire new project using:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

And it worked, but I still can't figure out how to get it to work in my existing project.

How do I add support for this to my current existing project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
npm install -s react-scripts@next
```

Comment: Didn't work for my existing project. I get an error after
Starting the development server...

Comment: It will work for a new project. Can you tell us the error?

Comment: My project breaks when I bump react-scripts from 3.2.0 -> 3.3.0. I get "Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory".